# Use order by in union all

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
select username,amount from employee
union all
select '' as username,sum(amount) from employee
order by cast(username as decimal)
```

username start from 1000

when I use this query it always display highest username to smallest username

I want to display smallest username to highest username

What I do for that?

Comment: order by cast(username as decimal) desc

Comment: what is the datatype of `username`? what are the sample records of username?

Comment: @Alexey he wants ascending order. By default the order by displays in ascending order!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it by wrapping in in a subquery,

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT username, amount from employee
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '' as username, sum(amount) from employee
    ) x
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN username = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASC, 
          CAST(username AS SIGNED) ASC
```

Comment: thanks John Woo, If I use this query it display smallest to highest but sum of amount is display at first. I want sum of amount to last